# Absolute max and min on a delimited function

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, maxima-minima

I'm struggling with an excise that I can't find a way to solve. I need to find the absolute minimum and maximum on a function:
$$f(x,y)=x-y$$

on the curve defined as:
$$x^4+y^4+xy=0$$

I tried with the Langrage multiplier method but the system does not have solution (or it's too complex for me). I don't think I can use polar coordinates because it is not a circumference.

Solutions should be $(-\sqrt2/2;\sqrt2/2)$ - minimum and $(\sqrt2/2;-\sqrt2/2)$ - maximum

Thanks.

Comment: Lucky Guess ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2pif6x55vr

Comment: Thanks Donald, graphically it's clear, but I do not understand how to calculate the points which should be $(-\sqrt2/2;\sqrt2/2)$ - minimum and $(\sqrt2/2;-\sqrt2/2)$ - maximum.

Comment: The symmetry makes it clear that the extrema occur at $x=-y$.

Comment: Ok, but this is an excesize of an exam. I do not have access to any fancy graphical design tool, and I have really no idea how $x^4+y^4+xy=0$ looks like...I need to find the point with calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $g(x,y)=x^4+y^4-xy$. Then $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g$ gives
$$(1,-1)=\lambda (4x^3+y,4y^3+x),$$
so $1=\lambda (4x^3+y)$ and $-1=\lambda(4y^3+x)$. Note $\lambda\neq 0$ since then we would have $1=0$.

Hence $\lambda (4x^3+y)=-\lambda(4y^3+x)$. 
 Dividing by $\lambda$ gives
$4x^3+y=-4y^3-x$, which rearranges to
$$4x^3+4y^3+x+y=0,$$
or
$$(x+y)(4(x^2+y^2-xy)+1)=0.$$
Hence $x=-y$ or $4(x^2+y^2-xy)+1=0$, but we cannot have $4(x^2+y^2-xy)+1=0$ since
$$4(x^2+y^2-xy)+1=4\left(x-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2+3y^2+1\geq1.$$
Now we have $x=-y$, this can be substituted into $g(x,y)=0$ to find the values of $x$ and $y$ at the critical points.